# How to disable keyboard on a user using ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen, user

I am trying to create an automated monitoring system that other people can see but cannot do commands.

I have a problem where the user is automatically connected to a screen where the monitoring is happening but they can close the screen.

I would like some way so that any user except root to have their keyboard disabled.

Comment: do you want it to make users just check mail or something like that?

Comment: I run a Siri Proxy but I need other people to monitor it so I am trusted with that the proxy does.

Comment: So, you just want other people run a specific application?

Comment: Yes, I have setup, so when the user logs in they are automatically connected to a screen. The script runs "screen -x root/" All I need it to do is stop the keyboard from typing and make them control the screen.

Comment: @MuktadirMiah I added screen-related stuff to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Screen-based solution

You can configure screen to open a window, share the session and write-lock it for `USER` on startup.  Put the following commands in your `.screenrc`:

```
screen 1
multiuser on
aclchg <USER> +x detach
writelock on
```

This prevents the `USER` from executing any commands except `detach` (so he can log-off).

### X-based solution

You can expose your X display read-only via vnc

```
x11vnc -viewonly -display :0
```

where `:0` is the display number.  You can also create an X server by the `-create` option.

On the ordinary user accounts you can start up all X sessions with the vnc client as the only program.

Comment: Do you know any way to make user connect to the screen as soon as they log in? And make it automatically run the "multiuser on.." when I make a new screen e.g. I make a new screen by typing "screen -S 1234" Then the "multiuser on", "aclchg <USER> -x ?", etc runs automatically.

Comment: You can put the commands into root's `.screenrc`.  For the user append the lines `screen -x root/` and `logout`  to the `.bash_login` and make sure bash is the login shell for the user (`usermod $USER -s /bin/bash`).  If you like the answer, you can also vote it up.